# Equivalent space navigation bar buttons in ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

How can I create nav bar buttons like facebook Lite does using ionic2
,[Sample facebook navbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45s1m.jpg)

Comment: override and adjusted .bar-button-md parameters and its working now..

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go through with [Grid concept in Ionic 2 documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#grid). So basically you need to create a div and you need to divide that div in two parts. (As for your facebook example)One section will include news feed, friend Requests, Messages , Notification and the other section will include search and menu button. For that Initially you need to divide div in to 80% and 20% ratio (just for an example) and again you need to divide first section in to 4 equivalent sections. So here is an example code for that:-

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col width-80>
        <ion-col width-25><button ion-button>News Feed</button></ion-col>
        <ion-col width-25><button ion-button>Notifications</button></ion-col></ion-col>
        <ion-col width-25><button ion-button>Requests</button></ion-col></ion-col>
        <ion-col width-25><button ion-button>Messages</button></ion-col></ion-col>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-20>
        <ion-col width-50><button ion-button>Search</button></ion-col></ion-col>
        <ion-col width-50><button ion-button>Menu</button></ion-col></ion-col>
      </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
```